# Where can I find classified documents for Mongor bundle in Laravel?

Tags: mongodb, bundle, laravel, laravel-3, mongor

I have been searching the internet for 4 hours, yet could no find any good documentations on how to use Mongor in Laravel. Any references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not believe there is any documentation for Mongor, the last change made by the author was in July 2010 (except merging pull requests up to 4 months ago).  The only post I can find that may be of any help is:

- http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=10133#p10133

Comment: Oh no ;( ...#$^%#33^... at least some one could tell me how could i insert a new document in my collection :P, any tutorial ... any samples ... anything ...

Comment: From what I can see, Mongor is designed to act like Laravel's [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent), so once you've extended `Mongor\Model` you should be able to make new Things and ->save() them.